# google places and geocode not returning full results list

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I am doing some mapping work and need to find latitude and longitude of villages in india many of which are small and rural.  I am having trouble finding the full set of locations with the same name, for example a village named 'Kallanai' (see api links below, note they need appropriate keys for the places API to run on your computer).  I can find the one I'm looking for in google maps by entering www.google.co.in/maps/place/Kallanai into the browser however it will not turn up in the geocoder or places api without specifying the associated pin code (analogous to zip-code).  Can anyone explain why the basic searches for either the geocode or places API using the village name alone do not return the village with the pincode 625501 in the results?

e.g.

Google places:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kallanai&sensor=false&key=enter your key

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kallanai+625501&sensor=false&key=enter your key

will post google geocode links in follow up as stackoverflow will not let me include more than 2 links in my post without more points.

Comment: Google geocode api links  (do not require key) 

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kallanai&sensor=false&region=uk

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kallanai+625501&sensor=false&region=uk

Comment: This is a very interesting question. My guess would be that Google Maps applies some sort of heuristic to quickly find locations in the API. If the other two Kallanais have larger population or greater overall significance, it would choose these two first, and terminate the search there. In other words, it probably searches top-down (in terms of significance); if it finds things that match the criteria, it returns those and ends; otherwise, it keeps going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a world where autocomplete is common and almost taken for granted, Google Maps has (long) switched to showing just the one results your most likely looking for.

[Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) might get you more of what you're looking for, but it would still be a sub-optimal fit for database-like queries like this. It works best when you have users typing, each of them knowing which Kallanai they want, so they can select the suggestion that matches, and they can add details (e.g. PIN code) to get it if the suggestion doesn't show up at first (max 5 suggestion show each time).

Google does Geocoding in a different way from classic GIS databases. To obtain *all* cities [with a given name] in a given country, you'd probably need a database like [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/maps/showOnMap?q=Paris&country=US&featureClass=P) or [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-populated-places/).